# How can I call two functions with same name from two source files in R?

Tags: r

I have two files, for example "aa.R" and "bb.R", both have a function "foo()".

How can I call the two functions with the same name from my console?

For example in "aa.R"

```
hi <- function(){
  print("hi, aa")
  }
```

in "bb.R"

```
hi <- function(){
  print("hi, bb")
  }
```

I tried the following:

```
source("aa.R")
source("bb.R")
aa::hi()
```

But it doesn't work. How can I get the `hi()` function from "aa.R"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` into separate environments:

```
aa <- new.env()
bb <- new.env()

source(textConnection('hi <- function(){
  print("hi, aa")
}'), local = aa)

source(textConnection('hi <- function(){
  print("hi, bb")
}'), local = bb)

aa$hi()
#[1] "hi, aa"
bb$hi()
#[1] "hi, bb"
```

However, I suggest that you seriously consider building two packages from your two files. Then you could use `::`.

Comment: This answer is right, but it's still so ugly to deal with more than one environment. I want to give you a plus one but I just can't.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. No seriously, just don't. You're just asking for irreproducible errors and unecessary confusion.

Change one of the two names. Or, rename them when they are called so it doesn't matter if they are overwritten.

```
source("aa.R")
hi_aa <- hi
source("bb.r")
hi_bb <- hi
```